# Check if a variable contain any ipv6 address or not in c

Tags: c

Let suppose in a structure

```
struct in6_addr
{
    unsigned char s6_addr[16];
}x;
```

`s6_addr` contains any ipv6 address in binary form. Now I want to retrieve that ipv6 address and print in human readable format. I know to print ipv6 address in human readable form we use `inet_ntop()`. But before printing ipv6 address or before using `inet_ntop()`, I just want to ensure that this variable contain any ipv6 address or any value then only use `inet_ntop()`

```
 if(/* Condition */)
 {
 /* if condition becomes true then only use inet_ntop() */
     inet_ntop();
 }
```

Comment: Since any 128bit value is an IPv6 address there is nothing to check

Comment: You have to come up with your own semantics if it's your own code that fills the ipv6 address. If you call some API, it should be documented what you get back for an *invalid* or *non-existent* address if such a return value is possible.

Comment: You may be referring to the text depiction of the value, where the `:` or `::` or `.` characters are used to delineate between bytes, such as: `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx` for purpose of human readability.  If so, you can refer to _[this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzai2/rzai2compipv4ipv6.htm#rzai2compipv4ipv6__compaddress)_ (click address) which compares ipv4 and ipv6 characteristics.  But the value itself does not contain these characters, nor does it need them to resolve an address.

Comment: @ryyker these patterns do not apply to the struct which holds the IPv6 address. In the byte array you do not have any of these separators but only plain octets.

Comment: @Gerhardh - this is what I have implied... _But the value itself does not contain these characters, nor does it need them to resolve an address._